# Criteria Query returnig all records

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

**SQL :**

```
String hql1 = "SELECT /* PARALLEL(MVR,16) PARALLEL(MVRS,16)*/  * FROM
ICM MINUS SELECT I1.* FROM ICM I1 , C1_ICM_STATIC I2 WHERE
I1.METRIC_DIRECTION=I2.METRIC_DIRECTION AND
I1.METRIC_NAME=I2.METRIC_NAME AND I1.METRIC_UNIT=I2.METRIC_UNIT AND
I1.TERMINATION_POINT_ID=I2.TERMINATION_POINT_ID AND
I1.TERMINATION_POINT_NAME=I2.TERMINATION_POINT_NAME AND
I1.TERMINATION_POINT_TYPE=I2.TERMINATION_POINT_TYPE";
```

**Criteria Query**

```
icms1 = (List<ICM>) session.createCriteria(ICM.class, hql1).list();
```

I have executed `hql1` using SQL Developer then I got only `one result`, but when I have integrated SQL Query with `Criteria` it returning me `all records` in `ICM` table.

If `SQL` query returning only one result in SQL Developer, Why criteria API returning all records in `ICM` table?

Comment: In criteria query you have to add restrictions for adding where clause conditions.

Comment: You may be on a hurry at work, but still try to spend some effort when asking others to spend time on *your* question. `returnig`, `returing` or `executred` are not difficult to spell out correctly.

Comment: @DipenAdroja But in my query I have written all the conditions with where clause.

Comment: Criteria won't create where clause directly from given hql. I think you are misunderstood something here. Please provide some more details about this.

Comment: @DipenAdroja I have updated my qustion, added query in it I am just passing this query to criteria api.

Comment: Hi if this helped you, then please mark the question solved and chose the answer that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why criteria API returning all records in ICM table?

Technically you are not using criteria api for associations.

Try something like this.
[Refer.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations)

```
 return criteria.createCriteria(A.class)
           .createCriteria("b", "join_between_a_b")
           .createCriteria("c", "join_between_b_c")
           .createCriteria("d", "join_between_c_d")
           .add(Restrictions.eq("some_field_of_D", someValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to read API documentation.

[The second `Session.createCriteria()` argument](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createCriteria%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) is the alias that you want to assign to the root entity. It's not a HQL query. HQL queries are not executed using `Session.createCriteria()`. They're executed using [`Session.createQuery()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

BTW, your query is not a HQL query at all. It's a SQL query. SQL and HQL are 2 different languages. To execute a SQL query, you need [createSQLQuery()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29).